# how to go from character to usable expression in R from a list?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I have a `data.table` `df` with various columns `x1,x2,x3,etc...` (no actual pattern in the name though) and I want to generically pass in a "config" for a variable amount of columns to do something. For example, produce a list of column plots. What I envision is saying something like this:

```
col.plot.list <- list(list(col='x2', seg=c(0,6)), list(col='z17', seg=NULL))
```

then being able to pass that to a function that will return a list of plots for the columns interpreting elements of each sublist to configure the plot in different ways. In this example, something like this:

```
gen.plots <- function(col.plot.list) {
    lapply(col.plost.list, function(x) {
        ggplot(df, aes(cumsum(x$col)) #plus geoms & optionally leverage x$seg if not NULL
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering though is how to turn the string corresponding to the column name back to a usable expression that I can pass to things like `df$x$col` or `aes(y=x$col)` etc.. does something for that exist? Or is there a different type I should use to save in the original list to start with which could help? I wouldn't want to save the full column vector as that wouldn't then allow me to do `data.table` operations in an `lapply`.

Comment: You are probably referring to `get()`. See `?get`

Comment: get seems to be working too in some of my examples, thanks for the reminder on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but maybe this example is useful. Basically, you need to use `aes_`, which can handle quoted expressions.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.table(x2 = 1:2, z17 = 3:4, y = 1:2)

col.plot.list <- list(list(col='x2', seg=c(0,6)), list(col='z17', seg=NULL))

gen.plots <- function(col.plot.list) {
  lapply(col.plot.list, function(x) {
    col <- x$seg
    xval <- as.name(x$col)
    ggplot(df, aes_(x = bquote(cumsum(.(xval))),
                   y = quote(y), 
                   color = if (is.null(col)) NULL else quote(col))) + 
      geom_point()
  })
}

gen.plots(col.plot.list)[[1]]
gen.plots(col.plot.list)[[2]]
```

If you just want to subset a data.table (or data.frame) this is a FAQ and you need to study `help("[")` and the data.table vignettes: `df[[col.plot.list[[1]]$col]]`

Comment: very interesting, im unfamiliar with `as.name` and what type that would be and `bquote`. I'll read up on those two. [apparenlty `name` is a class, did not know that]